# In GDB Python script, array indexing fails if frame’s language is Ada

Tags: ada, freertos, gdb-python

I have a [script](https://github.com/simonjwright/cortex-gnat-rts/blob/master/python/stacks.py) to work out how much free stack space there is in each FreeRTOS task. GDB’s language is set to `auto`. The script works fine when the current language is `c`, but fails when the current language is `ada`.

I have, in the class `Stacks`,

```
tcb_t = gdb.lookup_type("TCB_t")
int_t = gdb.lookup_type("int")
```

used to:

find {Ada task control block}.Common.Thread,

```
thread = atcb["common"]["thread"]
```

convert to a pointer to the FreeRTOS task control block,

```
tcb = thread.cast(Stacks.tcb_t.pointer()).dereference()
```

find the logical top of the stack

```
stk = tcb["pxStack"].cast(Stacks.int_t.pointer())
```

Now I need to loop logically down the stack until I find an entry not equal to the initialised value,

```
free = 0
while stk[free] == 0xa5a5a5a5:
    free = free + 1
```

which works fine if the current frame’s language is `c`, but if it’s `ada` I get

> Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> not an array or string: 
>   Error occurred in Python command: not an array or string

I’ve traced this to the expression `stk[free]`, which is being interpreted using the rules of the current language (in Ada, array indexing uses parentheses, so it would be `stk(free)`, which is of course illegal since Python treats it as a function call).

I’ve worked round this by

```
def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
    gdb.execute("set language c")
    ...
    gdb.execute("set language auto")
```

but it seems wrong not to set the language back to what it was originally.

So,

- is there a way of detecting the current GDB language setting from Python?
- is there an alternate way of indexing that doesn’t depend on the current GDB language setting?

Comment: is there by any chance a benefit of overloading the python indexing operator `[]` and bind it to some custom C/Ada code (or define a custom function if overloading is not possible in python) ? maybe its iirrelevant ...